# Replace a character with another in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am using the following code in python to receive data from a device.

```
from socket import *

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 30003    #our port from before
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096

sock = socket( AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ADDR))


def readlines(sock, recv_buffer=4096, delim='\n'):
    buffer = ''
    data = True
    while data:
        data = sock.recv(recv_buffer)
        buffer += data

        while buffer.find(delim) != -1:
            line, buffer = buffer.split('\n', 1)
            yield line.strip('\r\n')

    return

for line in readlines(sock):
    print line
```

And I am getting the output in following format:

```
MSG,2,0,0,8963AB,0,2015/02/06,15:03:27.380,2015/02/06,15:03:27.380,,0,7.5,343.0,10.152763,76.390593,,,,,,-1    MSG,2,0,0,8963AB,0,2015/02/06,15:03:28.630,2015/02/06,15:03:28.630,,0,7.5,348.0,10.152809,76.390593,,,,,,-1
```

I should get the output in following format:

```
'MSG','2','0','0','8963AB','0','2015/02/06','15:03:27.380','2015/02/06','15:03:27.380','','0','7.5','343.0','10.152763','76.390593','','','','','','-1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string with `,` as delimiter. Then append the elements to a list

```
appended_list = [x for x in original_list.split(',')]
```

Now the appended list will contain the strings like you wish

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner in python. This data is streaming data and cmes in continously. So I want to get each line in new format as it comes. So where actualy I should add your code.